# Reuse old published ASP.NET code for new WEB project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have old VS ASP.NET project that published on GoDaddy web site.
Unfortunately I lost my local source code. Now I decided to continue with this project.
I downloaded all files.
I already tried:

1. Create new Project from existing code using VS2019. Output type - Console Application. I restored all references and packages. I can't start this project to run as web project.
2. Create new ASP.NET Web Application project and added existing project. My new project starts, but I need to run the old one.
   What is correct way to accomplish it?
   Thanks in advance!
   Arkady

Comment: Are you able to download the c# files as well?

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the folder as a web site, and NOT open as application (since you don't have a sln project file anyway.

Hence use/try this option:

[image]

If the folder of files you downloaded does have source code files, then you be ok.

However, if this was published as a web site application, then all source code is pre-compiled and stripped out. If that is the case, then you need the origional project.

However, if it was published as a asp.net web site

and NOT as

asp.net web site application?

Then you should be ok.

You know instant when you open a particular web page in the site - if you can view code, then your are fine. If you don't have the source code, and don't see it, then this was published as a web site application, and thus source code was stripped and only the compiled output in the bin file was published along with the mark-up pages, but as such no code files are published to the server (some exceptions exist such as app_code, but in general, you MUST have the original source files and project if this was a web site application as opposed to just a web site.

Comment: Albert, thank you for you idea! Using you suggestion I stuck with next problem my code behind files were not recognizing field values from front page. It took a lot of time to find solution. For any one who will have same problem: we need to mention correct CodeFile in front page. As I understand it happens because now the declared as Web Site and not Web Application.

Comment: A good suggestion. If the original was web site, then that change should not be required. If you do have a choice, then without question start using a web site application. Even for that existing site. the main issue with choosing web site application, is some hosting environments may not work. If you have your own web server to deploy to, then without question, change over and create a web site application. But, just opening the folder as web site does allow you to work against the live web folder and no publishing is required - some developers do like that ability over using web application.